# Implement check all checkbox in react && angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm trying to implement check all feature on my checkbox element but I can't manage to do that.Can someone help ?

```
var FormattedDate = ReactIntl.FormattedDate;
var DiaryTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items : this.props.item,
            globalChecked: false
        };
    },
    changeSelection:function (i) {
       var state = this.state.items.map(function (element) {
           return {
             start:element.start,
               end:element.end,
               hours:element.hours,
               selected:(element === this.state.items[i] ? !element.selected:element.selected)
           };
       });
    },
    render: function(){
        var arrayItems =  this.state.items.map(function (item,i) {
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={item.selected} onChange={this.changeSelection(i).bind(this)}/></td>
                    <td><FormattedDate value={item.start}/></td>
                    <td><FormattedDate value={item.end}/></td>
                    <td>{item.hours}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="editButton"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {this.state.items[i].selected}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
                <table className="myTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox"/></th>
                    <th>Start Date:</th>
                    <th>End Date:</th>
                    <th id="hoursField">Hours:</th>
                    <th id="editField">Edit:</th>
                        <th>selected:</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {arrayItems}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                    <td colSpan="4">
                        <button className="myButton" id="addPeriodButton">Add period</button>
                        <button className="myButton">Remove period</button>
                        <button className="myButton">Set result from merge</button>
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
        );
    }
 });
```

I', taking data from my controller:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.resultProps = {
            item:[]
        }
        $scope.firstArrayProps =  {
            item:[{start:new Date(),end:22,hours:3,selected:false},{start:22,end:33,hours:44,selected:false}]
        }
        $scope.secondArrayProps =  {
            item:[{start:22,end:33,hours:44,selected:false}]
        }
..... more code here
```

and index.html..

```
<body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
<!--<div id="diaryWrapper">-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;<diary-template props="firstArrayProps" result="resultProps" ></diary-template>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<div class="mergeWrapper">&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<button class="myButton" id="mergeButton" ng-click="runMerge()">Merge diaries</button>&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash;</div>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--&lt;!&ndash;<diary-template props="secondArrayProps" result="resultProps" ></diary-template>&ndash;&gt;-->
<!--</div>-->
<div class="tableWrapper">
<react-component name="DiaryTable" props="firstArrayProps" />
</div>

<div class="tableWrapper">
<react-component name="DiaryTable" props="secondArrayProps" />
</div>
```

If I'm doing wrong something else please feel free to tell me . Thank you !

Comment: What is it you hope the changeSelection function does? It doesn't return anything and looks like you're trying to modify state in place without using setState which you shouldn't do.

Comment: I was about to implement setState but its getting me error : items is not defined ??

Comment: At which point do you get that?

Comment: changeSelection is not right, instead of map, find or items[i] should be used. setState should be called as it is a controlled component. To copy an array, array.slice() should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The code for handleSelectAll should be:

```
handleSelectAll: function(e) {
  var items = this.state.items.slice();
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.selected: e.target.checked,
  });
  this.setState({ items: items });
}
```